Use AnimationClip to turn a material pitch black and then back to its original color
I have an object that has 2 materials, both using the URP/Lit shader. One of them is emissive and its color changes at runtime.
I would like to create an effect where the two materials become pitch black (think ventablack), and then gradually return to their original state.
Is it possible to achieve this effect using an animation clip created in Unity's animation editor?
I have very limited knowledge about lighting, shading and render pipelines, so I think using an animation clip for this effect would be the easiest since it's easy to tweak at edit time and to trigger at runtime, but I am also curious to know about other ways.
I have tried animating some of the MeshRenderer propreties in the animation editor, but:

For the non-emissive material, when I try to change its Material_Base Color to black, I can still see it being tinted by scene light
For the emissive material, even if I could find the right properties to animate, I am not sure how to proceed because I cannot hard-code the initial color, as it can change at runtime


I'd be inclined to make a custom shader graph that exposes a single "blackness" parameter that simultaneously drives albedo/smoothness/emission to zero, just to simplify this setup.

@dmgregory Your comment motivated me to finally learn Shader Graph, and it turns out it is quite trivial to achieve this as you suggested. I can even easily animate the exposed parameter in the Animator. If you want to add this as answer I can mark it as accepted. Note that I also had to drive the normals to 0 because otherwise I could still see light being reflected.

Good solution. I think you should get to post the answer, since you're the one who put in the work to execute it and problem-solve around the normals, and you have the graphs handy to make screenshots, whereas I'd have to make fake ones just for the sake of the answer.

Following the suggestion from @dmgregory, I used Shader Graph to solve this:

Create a new Lit Shader Graph (I am using URP)
Expose parameters for Smoothness, Base color, Emission color, and a float parameter to control the "blackout" effect
For each of Smoothness, Base color and Emission color, run them through a multiply node with the blackout parameter before piping the result to the corresponding input in the master node, such that when the blackout parameter is 0, everything is set to zero
To achieve pitch blackness you will also need to zero-out the normals in the same way; in my case my material was very simple and didn't require a normals map, so I instead used the "Normals" node set to "Tangent space"

You can now turn materials pitch black without messing with the scene's lighting, and you can even animate the blackout parameter in the Animator to create interesting transitions.
